# What are: Dynamic Apex Classes in Setup > Apex Classes

Tags: apex, external-services, pre-release, release-notes

What are `Dynamic Apex Classes`?

They are in a `Winter 23` preview org in:

> Setup > Apex Classes

In a section called `Dynamic Apex Classes` and they have a description of:

> Dynamic Apex extends your programming reach by interacting with Lightning Platform components.

I cannot find anything in the `Winter 23` release documentation:

- [Salesforce Winter ’23 Release Notes](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.salesforce_release_notes.htm&type=5&release=240)

Apart from maybe:

- [External Service: View Apex Names in Apex Class Viewer](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.external_services_rn_view_apex_classes.htm&type=5&release=240)

But the `Dynamic Apex Classes` description does not seem to align with `External Service`

Does anyone have anymore ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See [Manage Apex Classes - Dynamic Apex Classes](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.code_manage_packages.htm&type=5)

> **Dynamic Apex Classes** are dynamically generated to provide greater access into existing platform features. For example, if you register an API specification with External Services, all of the dynamically generated classes are listed under the **Dynamic Apex Classes** heading on the Apex Classes page. For the original source, click Open. Dynamic Apex Classes don't contribute toward the “[Maximum amount of code used by all Apex code in an org](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.240.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm#in_topic_size_gov_limits_section)” limit and are exempt from code coverage requirements.

Right now that section corresponds directly to the External Services - [View Apex Names in Apex Class Viewer](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.external_services_rn_view_apex_classes.htm&type=5&release=240), but over time other features are intended for that area. Hence the more generic name of "Dynamic Apex Classes".

Answer (score 5):

They are `Apex Classes` generated by `External Service`